# ubuntu 16.04 + hp envy 15: High temperature, never below 60°

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, motherboard, temperature, hp-envy

I have this system:

```
description: Notebook
product: HP ENVY 15 Notebook Pc (F4J09LA#ABM)
vendor: Hewlett-Packard
version: 09A2100000400000000000000
serial: 5CD5217NDD
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 vsyscall32
configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5335KV G=N L=CON B=HP S=ENV X=Null frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=F4J09LA#ABM uuid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-705A0F1CFBCD
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: 228D
   vendor: Hewlett-Packard
   physical id: 0
   version: 77.12
   serial: PEMJK018J2100U
   slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: Insyde
      physical id: e
      version: F.04
      date: 05/15/2014
      size: 128KiB
      capacity: 4032KiB
      capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 2d
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
      serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      slot: U3E1
      size: 3057MHz
      capacity: 3100MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 100MHz

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:  16.04
Codename: xenial

Linux test 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Two weeks ago or so, temp started going abnormally high even when doing the simplest thing (web browsing). I've got myself diagnosed that the video chipset was working bad and it needed "reflow". I had the chance to try a new motherboard but even after trying it out, the behavior is the same.

I've collected some stats and the weird thing is that temp does never go below 60°C (can't show the graph now 'cuz I need more reputation). You can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4kZm.png).

I can see the same from the `sensors` output.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +70.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +68.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +68.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

What worries me now is that even with a new motherboard I'm "getting" this high temp and the fans go crazy ...

I'm no expert but could this be due to a driver problem may be? My next guess is reinstalling ubuntu, but I want to get some info before going that way.

I've left the PC running on the BIOS and, from time to time, the fans do work, but I really do not know if that's a reasonable test.

Any hint is highly appreciated ...

thanks

lucas

Answer (score 0):

Overheating is a big and well-known problem of HP notebooks. And the overheating is observed irrespective of the installed operating system. You can advise only to thoroughly purge the grille of the cooling system and change the thermal paste, preferably on `liquid pro` or Arctic Silver 5 or Arctic Cooling MX-4 (which is slightly worse). Read more about thermal paste:

http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/cooling-air-pressure-heatsink,3058-9.html

Buy a stand for cooling + always look behind the left side of the laptop, so that nothing is nearby and does not block outflow of air